# Huffman decompresion

Tags: compression, huffman-code

Well i'm trying to implement function which will decide if given tree match to compressed file, well 'trying' is little "misrepresentation" i just dont know how to implement such functionality. 
I cant just figure out,because sometimes bytes of compressed file can match to tree from other file, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

I suggest reading up on Huffman compression -- perhaps Wikipedia: [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) and a few of the pages it links to.
Then edit your question to describe what you're trying to understand.
Could you use an actual question mark?

Huffman compression algorithms typically produce compressed files that contain a "header" with all the information necessary to reconstruct the tree, and a "body" with the compressed bitstream.

If you splice the "header" from one compressed file with the "body" of some other compressed file, the decompressor can't tell that anything is wrong -- the decompressor will happily produce "decompressed" gibberish.

Every possible sequence of bits can be "decoded" by every possible Huffman tree.
But the *correct* original file for some compressed bitstream can only be produced by the one *correct* Huffman tree.

It is usually not possible to decide, given only a the "body" compressed bitstream and a "header" (or the full Huffman tree reconstructed from that header), whether they are the real body and real header from a single real compressed file, or whether one came from one compressed file and the other came from some other compressed file.

Comment: thats kinde of answer i expected, well now i', checking if tree match file with one additional field in each bst leaf it has a value with character appearance if while decompressing i will not zero that value that will means tree does not match file